# ¿Cómo elimino líneas cuando paso el mouse por un elemento con la propiedad "transform = scale()"?

Tags: html, css, css3

En el siguiente código, al momento de mostrarlo en el navegador y pasar el mouse por encima del elemento (:hover), el elemento aumenta de tamaño (comportamiento normal), pero al cambiar la posición del mouse, aparecen unas líneas alrededor del contenedor al momento de "encogerse".

- La verdad creo que tiene que ver algo con la pantalla de mi computadora o alguna propiedad del navegador.
- Creo que el padding causa el problema pero no estoy seguro.

Captura (se pueden ver las líneas en la parte inferior y en la parte derecha):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      #selector {
        background-color: red;
        transition: 0.5s;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding: 10px 15px;
      }

      #selector:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="selector">sdsdsdsd</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿En que navegador se puede apreciar dicho comportamiento? Probé tu snipet en Chrome, Edge y Firefox y no lo puedo reproducir.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Chrome, pero también cheque en otros navegadores y pasa lo mismo (use Brave y Edge). En donde no paso fue en Firefox, creo que tiene que ver que estén basados en Chromium... Pero no estoy seguro